# rails 5 background file upload (not post processing), ideally with paperclip and delayed_job

Tags: file-upload, paperclip, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Recently moved an app to heroku and updated to rails 5. File uploads block dyno for too long.

I would like to put file uploads in a background process. Everything I read ends up being just an image post processing in the background. Is it possible to put the actual upload in a background process. If so, how?

I have read and succeeded in doing direct uploads to s3, but it is not what I am after. I like the validations paperclip is offering and there are already thousands of files stored with paperclip, so I do not want a change of the storage system (record ID).

Please only recommend ways of uploading the file in background, nothing about post processing, I know how to do that already.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the server (your Heroku Dyno) to do something with the upload in the background, it needs to have the file in the first place. The upload from the user’s browser to the server has to happen first so you won’t be able to make this non-blocking.

Having said that, uploading to S3 directly is one to avoid your server having to wait for the file. Your background job could then consist of downloading the file from S3, validating it and notifying the user of the outcome.

Ultimately that file has to be sent from the browser to somewhere the server can access it in it’s own time.

Comment: If I use S3 direct upload, then validate and move file in background process: Do you know how to do that, or do you have a helpful link? (except the direct upload, worked that out already). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom - I think I found the perfect solution: Shrine - a gem that covers precisely the issues and the solutions I am after!